# My laravel blade view always reloads all the js/css libraries

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've been working in my first laravel web app. Now I have a problem that is blowing my head up.

I have a home.blade.php view and I link all the css and javascript libraries on it (using the asset() function) as follows:

```html
...
///home.blade.php
<div class="left_nav_slidebar">
  <a href="customers">customers</a>
</div>
<div>
   @yield('content')
</div>
...            
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.1.0.js') }}"></script>
```

In the other hand I have another view named customers.blade.php, when my Controller (CustomerController) return this view, its reload the jquery and others libraries again.

```html
@extends('home')

@section('content')


<div class="list-group">
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <a>{{ $customer->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
</div>

@endsection
```

I don't know why it happens.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "reloads jquery and other libraries"? What do you expect exactly?

Comment: If you expect that only your customres.blade.php loads like in an ajax request, this doesnt works that way. The process renders all the extendend templates including the "master" template.

Comment: Really? and then I have to create a javascript ajax request? :(